# How to deserialize value of type from array value?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, api

I'm getting an error when trying to convert JSON to an object and I have no idea how I can solve this.

I am trying to map such JSON:

```
{
    "code": "USD",
    "rates": [
        {
            "effectiveDate": "2022-04-12",
            "mid": 4.2926
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`rates` property is **array** in json, `rates` field is **object** in your class. You need to deserialize in the same type - array to array/list, object to object, etc. Make the field array or list in class and you are good to go.

```
@Getter
public class CurrencyDto {
    private String code;
    private CurrencyRatesDto[] rates;
}
```

Comment: @boxieAnn iterate over the elements, you can call the methods for each element in the array. If you are sure there is always exactly one element you can do `rates.get(0).getMid()`, otherwise call `getMid()` for every element with a loop

Answer (score 0):

The error `Cannot deserialize value of type com.example.nbpmaster.webclient.dto.CurrencyRatesDto from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY` is clear.

The deserializer is expecting `rates` to be an Object, but it found a `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`, which is the char `[`.

You are trying to deserialize a JSON array into a Object (`CurrencyRatesDto`).

In your `CurrencyDto` class, change the `CurrencyRatesDto` to some sort of Collection or primitive array -- I used `List<CurrencyRatesDto>` in the following example

```
@Getter
public class CurrencyDto {
    private String code;
    private List<CurrencyRatesDto> rates;
}
```

Comment: @boxieAnn . . . Well, you have to iterate over the list and call `getMid()` and `getEffectiveDate()` in each object of the list. . .